# Jquery checkbox unchecks on submit

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, submit

My checkboxes are empty when page refreshes after submit. I would like to keep them checked. How can I do that in jquery?

Here is my jquery code.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(':checkbox.selectall').on('click', function () {
                $(':checkbox[id="' + $(this).data('checkbox-name') + '"]').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
                $( "#frm1" ).submit();
            });
            $(':checkbox.checkme').on('click', function () {
                var _selectall = $(this).prop("checked");
                if (_selectall) {
                    $(':checkbox[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').each(function (i) {
                        _selectall = $(this).prop("checked");
                        return _selectall;
                    });
                }
                $(':checkbox[name="' + $(this).data('select-all') + '"]').prop("checked", _selectall);
                $( "#frm1" ).submit();
            });
        });
```

My html is as follows...

```
<input type='checkbox' id='selectall' name='sa_subcatinput[]' value='$row[id]'     
    data-checkbox-name='$row[id]' class='selectall'/></label></a></li>

<input type='checkbox' name='subcatinput[]' value='$test[id]' id='$test[category]' 
    class='checkme'  data-select-all='sa_subcatinput[]'/>
```

Comment: If it's a php page and you're submitting the form to the same page, just use post data to set the values of the checkboxes where you create them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this unless you send a value back to your page which indicates the checkbox to be checked.Since you said the page refreshes, a server communication is happened. So you may use ajax to keep the check box checked

Answer (score 0):

Pass a querystring parameter of the id or number or value or whatever of the checked checkbox.
request the parameter using server side code or a client-side javascript using a get parameter function (there on many on this site).

rechecked the box using your custom function and the value returned.

```
$('#ckeckbox1').val(unescape(getParam(document.URL,'checkbox1')));

function getParam(url,name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(url);
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}

function removeParameter(url, parameter) {
  var urlparts= url.split('?');
  if (urlparts.length>=2) {
    var urlBase=urlparts.shift(); //get first part, and remove from array
    var queryString=urlparts.join("?"); //join it back up

    var prefix = encodeURIComponent(parameter)+'=';
    var pars = queryString.split(/[&;]/g);
    for (var i= pars.length; i-->0;)               //reverse iteration as may be destructive
        if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0)!==-1)   //idiom for string.startsWith
            pars.splice(i, 1);
    url = urlBase+'?'+pars.join('&');
  }
  return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the code working with php. Here is the code I inserted in the input to make it work.

```
echo"<input type='checkbox' id='selectall' name='sa_subcatinput[]' value='$row[id]'
    data-checkbox-name='$row[id]' class='selectall'";
    if (isset($_POST['sa_subcatinput'])) {
        if (in_array($row['id'], $_POST['sa_subcatinput'])) {
            echo"checked='checked'";
        }
    }
echo"/>


echo"<input type='checkbox' name='subcatinput[]' value='$test[id]'
    id='$test[category]' class='checkme'  data-select-all='sa_subcatinput[]'";
    if (isset($_POST['subcatinput'])) {
        if (in_array($test['id'], $_POST['subcatinput'])) {
           echo"checked='checked'";
        }
    }
echo"/>
```